# Ubuntu "can't see everywhere" more than 2GB Ram

Tags: ram

I have an old notebook (compaq NX 7300 - 32bit cpu) perfectly working but pretty slow. It has 2GB Ram, I've tried upgrading to 3GB with 2 differents SODIMM (1GB each) taken from a broken laptop.

With both SODIMM (different brands) I have the same weird result: the BIOS see the 3GB but Ubuntu (16.04) still says 2 in both free and meminfo, but lshw can see the second memory module. The BIOS is upgraded to the latest version and does not have any memory configuration option.

Could you help me understanding?

uname

```
Linux ubumon 4.4.0-66-generic #87-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 3 15:27:09 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

free -m

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2005         687         121         250        1196         820
Swap:          2037          25        2012
```

meminfo

```
MemTotal:        2053932 kB
MemFree:          249548 kB
MemAvailable:     896096 kB
Buffers:          197416 kB
Cached:           881856 kB
SwapCached:         1464 kB
Active:           900048 kB
Inactive:         785352 kB
Active(anon):     393312 kB
Inactive(anon):   469320 kB
Active(file):     506736 kB
Inactive(file):   316032 kB
Unevictable:         204 kB
Mlocked:             204 kB
HighTotal:       1175368 kB
HighFree:         140016 kB
LowTotal:         878564 kB
LowFree:          109532 kB
SwapTotal:       2086908 kB
SwapFree:        2057492 kB
Dirty:               336 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        604944 kB
Mapped:           311724 kB
Shmem:            256504 kB
Slab:              76716 kB
SReclaimable:      56284 kB
SUnreclaim:        20432 kB
KernelStack:        3960 kB
PageTables:        11952 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:     3113872 kB
Committed_AS:    4487840 kB
VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
AnonHugePages:    151552 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       43000 kB
DirectMap2M:      870400 kB
```

lshw memory

```
  *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: a
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 3GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 975 MHz (1,0 ns)
             product: EBE11UE6ACUA-8G-E
             vendor: 7F7FFE0000000000
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0E7B1B6A
             slot: DIMM #1
             size: 1GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 975MHz (1.0ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR2 Synchronous 975 MHz (1,0 ns)
             product: 99P5471-013.A00LF
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DIMM #2
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 975MHz (1.0ns)
```

cpuinfo

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 14
model name  : Intel(R) Celeron(R) M CPU        440  @ 1.86GHz
stepping    : 12
microcode   : 0x54
cpu MHz     : 1861.861
cache size  : 1024 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 1
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 1
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fdiv_bug    : no
f00f_bug    : no
coma_bug    : no
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 10
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss tm pbe nx constant_tsc arch_perfmon bts aperfmperf pni monitor tm2 xtpr pdcm dtherm
bugs        :
bogomips    : 3723.72
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 32 bits physical, 32 bits virtual
power management:
```